# Soapy aftertaste in wine, fermentation temperature?

Tags: fermentation, temperature, wine, off-flavor, aftertaste

I generally find my homebrew wine (just from a regular kit) has a soapy kind of aftertaste. I'm wondering if this might be down to fermentation temperature or something, I'm taking as many precautions as possible sanitation-wise and folowing instructions to the letter

Comment: What sanitiser are you using?

Comment: Vin Classe Steriliser and Cleaner

Answer (score 2):

This article may hold the answers you seek: https://winemakermag.com/1254-soapy-wines-vintage-dates-wine-wizard

"...I suspect you’ve got a fatty acid issue caused by your stuck/sluggish fermentation. S. cerevisiae can emit fatty acids when under fermentative stress..."

Stuck fermentations can be caused by a lack of dissolved oxygen in the first few days of the fermentation. When you add your wine to your fermenter give it a good shake to help dissolve some oxygen and get a healthy start for your yeast.

Comment: Too little nutrients and low pH can cause stuck fermentations, as well.

Comment: very true, but a kit should provide all nutrients and the pH required.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Just got back into the brewing game so I'm hoping things will improve!